# Angular 1 - Global filter (search) on All values in an Array/JSON

Tags: angularjs

I'm using an old AngularJS 1.x,  I have a JSON object with various key/values. How can I filter on ANY of the values in the array. I want to create a global search input field and enter any value that can be found in the data. I'd like to do the search() in the controller. Something like this..

```
$scope.search = function(searchTerm){
  // Loop through objects  - angular.forEach
     // Loop through key/values
      // return matches
}
```

The search will return the list of objects that have the value (indexof) >-1 in one of it's values
thanks in advance

Comment: This question is way too broad and needs clarification: What is the search function supposed to return when there are no matches, when there is a single match, when there are multiple matches? Also, can it be assumed that all object values will be of type string? Will the search match only on the beginning of the value string, end of the value string, or anywhere in the value string? Should it support only exact matching or fuzzy matches? Will you be able to search using regular expressions or just plain text. Please provide a plunker that demonstrates what you have tried thus far.

Comment: You can use the [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) filter for this. If the objects have string values, then `searchTerm` will do a string match on the object properties for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

in HTML

```
Enter subject: <input type = "text" ng-model = "searchText">
Subject:
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat = "studentInfo in students | filter: searchText">
  </li>
</ul>
```

searchText will filter all fields in studentInfo.

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple using angular js 1 concept

```
<input type="text"  value="Search" ng-model="searchquery">

<div ng-repeat="datalist in datalists | filter:searchquery">
 <span>Name : {{ datalist.name }}</span>
 <span>Age : {{ datalist.age }}</span>
 <span>Age : {{ datalist.Designation }}</span>
</div>
```

[Using Angular js 1](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2015/04/angular-js-basic-search-and-filter-data.html)

[Using Angular 2](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/03/simple-search-using-pipe-in-angular-2.html)